# Xpath how to extract all texts in a scope?

Tags: xpath

```
<div class="main">
     <p><a href="#">Peter</a> got some troubles.</p>
     <p>I gave him my hand.</p>
     <p>But <a href="#">Sam</a> didn't.</p>
</div>
```

How can I extract all texts in the div.main with xpath?

I've tried `string(//div[@class="main"]/p)`, but it only extracted the first line:

> Peter got some troubles.

But I hope I can process all lines like:

> Peter got some troubles.
>   I gave him my hand.
>   But Sam didn't.

Comment: The string value of the `div` element should give you what you want. In other words, take off the `/p` at the end of your XPath expression. The problem with your expression is that `string()` takes only the first node in the nodeset.

Comment: Oh really!!
I solved it. Thank you. : )

Answer (score 0):

The string value of the `div` element should give you what you want. In other words, take off the `/p` at the end of your XPath expression. The problem with your expression is that `string()` takes only the first node in the nodeset.